# How to use enviroment variable that is set in docker composer

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, codeigniter-3

I am using docker container that runs codeigniter application and I have setted enviroment variable for base url in docker composer.yml like:

```
version: '3.4' services:
    app:
        image: WEBPORTAL_VERSION
        ports:
            - port_key:port_num
        environment:
            - BASE_URL=http://example.com
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            placement: 
                constraints:
                    - node.role == manager
```

Now, I want to access the environment key i.e. base url in codeigniter application

I am using:

> $_config['base_url']=getenv('BASE_URL');

where BASE_URL is key initialized in docker composer file above.

The problem here is getenv do not fetch from environment set in docker composer?

Comment: did you do a fresh build of the container?

Comment: try $_ENV['variable_name']

Comment: I have tried $_ENV['variable_name']  too but doesnot worked @BugHunter

Comment: Seems weird to me, with what @BugHunter said you should be able to access the variable value, have you tried to print it directly on the console? Something like `printenv | more`? Could you post the results? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ReynierPM I am not getting any error  just the value is blank for getenv

Comment: I got the env value from docker composer but its ignoring http:// and in source page its showing only example.com, why its ignoring http://

Answer (score 1):

Finally! solved the problem, by default in php-fpm config file was taking

```
 clear_env = yes
```

which is the default value, I changed it and updated as

```
clear_env=no
```